# Disable button after post using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, button

I would like to have a function to add an onclick event to my form buttons to get them disabled in order to avoid double posting.

```
<form>
   <button onclick="disable(this)" type="submit">post</button>
</form>
<script> function disable(button){ $(button). ??? }</script>
```

Ani idea or tip? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button must be an `input` element (if you don't submit the form via JavaScript). A `<button>` element has no attribute `type` and setting it will have no effect.
I also suggest to attach the `click` handler via jQuery:

```
<form>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="post" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript>
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
</script>
```

**Reference:** [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: How about `this.disabled = true`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(button).attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: If any, it should be `$('button')`.

Comment: @Felix: I think his intention is for it to be in the `disable` function from the question, which has a `button` parameter that gets `this` from the onclick.

Comment: i will try this on e first because it fits best with my code and let you  know. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="this.disabled='disabled'" type...>
```

Comment: onclick is dirty. attaching handlers is much better

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just target a button:

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

If you want a function:

```
function diableButton(bID){
    $(bID).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Call it using something like:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    disableButton($('input[type=submit]', this));
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use a wrapper function for `.attr('disabled','disabled')` if you're doing a jQuery `.submit()`.

Comment: Tbh only because the user asked for a function, if you had multiple forms on one page and you only wanted to disable the form button: see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/nKkKR/1/ you could be using an ajax call within the .submit() so you don't the button being pressed again for that form.