# Simplest way to disable button on submission of a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been trying to find the "right" way to prevent double submits of forms.  There are lots of related posts on SO but none of them hit the spot for me.  Two questions below.

Here is my form

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
    <button class="once-only">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is my first attempt to disable double submits:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".once-only").click(function(){
        this.disabled = true;
        return true;
    });
});
```

This is the approach suggested here: [Disable button after post using JS/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852847/disable-button-after-post-using-js-jquery). That post suggests the submitting element must be an input rather than a button, but testing both makes no difference.  You can try it yourself using this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uT3hP/

As you can see, this disables the button, but also prevents submission of the form.  In cases where the submitting element is a button and an input element.

**Question 1:** why does this click handler stop submission of the form?

Searching around some more I find this solution (from [Why doesn't my form post when I disable the submit button to prevent double clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400616/why-doesnt-my-form-post-when-i-disable-the-submit-button-to-prevent-double-clic))

```
if($.data(this, 'clicked')){
    return false;
} else{
    $.data(this, 'clicked', true);
    return true;
}
```

You can play with this using this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uT3hP/1/

This does work, but...

**Question 2:**  Is this the best we can do?

I thought this would be an elementary thing.  Approach 1 does not work, approach 2 does, but I don't like it and sense there must be a simpler way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable submit button on form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). In this case, it should look something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Here is a working jsFiddle (made by Mike) - http://jsfiddle.net/gKFLG/1/.

If your submit-button is *not* a direct child of the form-element you will need to replace `children` with `find`. Additionally, your submit-button may also be a `button` element instead of an `input` element. E.g. This is the case if you are using [Bootstrap horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal). Below is a different version of the snippet:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Demo jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/devillers/fr7gmbcy/

Comment: @MikeHogan The jsFiddle you posted to me seems to be using an on-click handler instead of my on-submit, I think this may be why. I'll try to take another look once I get back from work

Comment: @MikeHogan Thanks, I'll update that into my answer if that's ok (for future viewers) and will credit you for it.

Answer (score 59):

Simple and effective solution is

```
<form ... onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Source: [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/doublesubmit/)

Comment: By far the best solution IMO. It works with validations, and doesn't require any external libraries.

Comment: @mike-hogan I'd say this should be the accepted answer - works and is by far simplest.

Comment: simplest and effective to use!

Comment: The `return true;` is not needed.

Comment: The next code works with jQuery Validation plugin:
<form onsubmit="if ($(this).valid()) myButton.disabled = true" ...

Comment: By far the least complicated and simplest solution which actually worked...Thanks :)

Comment: this solution however does not send the `name` attribute in the form

Answer (score 4):

Similarly Ive seen a few examples, this one allows you to alter how long the button is disabled for, through timeout. It also only triggers on a form submit rather than on the buttons click event, which originally caused me a few issues.

```
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var button = $('#button');
        var oldValue = button.value;
        var isDisabled = true;

        button.attr('disabled', isDisabled);

        setTimeout(function () {
            button.value = oldValue;
            button.attr('disabled', !isDisabled);
        }, 3000)
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".once-only").click(function(){
      this.submit();
      this.disabled = true;
      return true;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
<form class="form-once-only" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
    <button type="submit" class="once-only">Send</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form.form-once-only").submit(function () {
        $(this).find(':button').prop('disabled', true);
    });
}
```