# Prevent Double Submission

Tags: javascript, form-submit, disable

i have a project on PHP, MySQL and using the CodeIgniter Framework, i have a page where the user submits an order, but the problem is that it takes a while for the system to process it and in the meantime if the user presses the submit button it will be submitted again.

What i am trying to do is to disable the button once it is pressed.
Here is the button code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <!-- begin panel -->
             <input type="hidden" name="order_status" value="0" />
                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success saveit saveorderf_"><?php echo "Save";?></button>
        <!-- end panel -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What i have tried so far is using the

```
onClick="this.disabled=true;
```

but it only disables the button with out the form being submitted.

Any ideas what i might be missing here .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your code with this:

```
onclick="this.disabled = true; form.submit();"
```

the `form.submit();` will do the job for you

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the button after form is submitted.

reference: [Simplest way to disable button on submission of a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529836/simplest-way-to-disable-button-on-submission-of-a-form)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.once-only').submit(function(){
        $(this).children('button').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form method="POST" class="once-only">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
    <button >Send</button>
</form>
```

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gKFLG/1/

Comment: No mention of jquery on this question