# Javascript hangs after button disabled

Tags: javascript

This code appears to hang some browsers after disabling the submit button. The code works as expected on Firefox 119 on a Linux desktop. It fails on the same desktop using the Chromium browser and on an iPad using Firefox. It has also failed on a Windows desktop.
The javascript does change the text of the button and disable it. The problem is the browser does not return to the server.

If the line, "requestBtn.disabled = true;" is commented out, the code works as expected on all browsers.

Any insight is appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const requestSpinner = document.getElementById('request-spinner');
  const requestBtnCard = document.getElementById('card-button');
  const requestBtnRequest = document.getElementById('submit-request');

  requestSpinner.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  requestSpinner.style.display = 'none';

  const requestBtn = requestBtnCard ? requestBtnCard : requestBtnRequest;

  requestBtn.addEventListener('click', 
    () => {
      requestBtn.disabled = true;
      requestBtn.innerText = 'Processing ...';

      requestSpinner.style.display = 'inline-block';
      requestSpinner.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit' id='submit-request' 
      class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>Request Tickets</button>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status" id='request-spinner'>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Processing ...</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"The problem is the browser does not return to the server."* - Can you clarify what you mean by that?  I've updated the question to a runnable code snippet.  In that example, please indicate what specifically isn't working as expected.

Comment: The button doesn't call any server.  The button doesn't remove the disabled state after a server would return a result.

Comment: disabling the button is like cancelling the action of the click. You would need to add a delay to the line where you set the disabled state.

Comment: It seems like the issue you're facing might be related to the synchronous nature of the JavaScript execution, leading to a delay in the actual submission of the form. When you disable the button, it might interfere with the default form submission behavior. Try using the submit event on the form instead of the click event on the button. This way, you can prevent the default form submission, perform your processing, and then manually submit the form when you're ready.

Comment: @David Specifically, the javascript disables the button and changes the text as expected. However, the form is not posted back to the server to process the input and continue to the next window.

Comment: To make it clearer, the snippet of HTML is contained within <form action="<link>"<fieldset>...</fieldset></form> tags. The desired result is disabling the submit button to prevent double entry while the server processes the input.

Answer (score 0):

The submit event is called right after the click event (on any form button).

By disabling the button before the submit, you probably confused Chromium which doesn't know it has to call the submit event.

**The easiest solution is to disable the button inside the submit call.**

Here is a code that will disable all buttons from all submitted forms :

```
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach((form)=> {
   form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
      form.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]').forEach((button)=> {
         button.disabled = true;
      });
   });
});
```

Here is another solution to insert in the HTML, which comes from another thread about this issue :
[Simplest way to disable button on submission of a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529836/simplest-way-to-disable-button-on-submission-of-a-form)

```
<form ... onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```